# Transparent LinearLayout with buttons (Android)

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I'm trying to make a menu with buttons, and my problem is that i want this menu to be over a camera view (I'm working on Augmented Reality).
But if I make my menu appear it makes the background black instead of having the video of my camera.

Any ideas how to make this background transparent? I tried with :

```
menu.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

but there is no modification :/...

Comment: have u declared the colour in your style.xml file ?

Comment: Actually i'm making the menu pragmatically, so no i didn't declare it.

Comment: OK. Then you can change the background of the menu as any transperent image. Or you can change the theme in Manifest file to black so that can shows the white background in your Application.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't thought about a transparent image.

Comment: If you like my answer then please upvote me. Thanks.

Comment: you can use the .png format image with size of your menu. That can sure help you an solve your problem.

Comment: Hello D4r7h, if you like my Answer or suggestion then u should have to upvote me. .

Comment: I don't know how to upvote your answer, I'm new here :/

Comment: I have answer in your question. Now select the up aero button near my answer. Its upvote to me.

Comment: ok i don't have enough reputaion to upvote, but I accepted the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. Then you can change the background of the menu as any transperent image. Or you can change the theme in Manifest file to black so that can shows the white background in your Application

Answer (score 0):

Try: `menu.setBackgroundColor(Color.alpha(0));`

Comment: how is this different from the `menu.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);` mentioned in the question?